# Unexpected results when using Replace()

Tags: sql, replace

Trying to Replace() characters:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(NetworkMemberId,'é','e'),'í','i'), 'ó','o'),'ñ','n')
```

but it is converting all e's, i's, o's, and n's, even upper case.

I tried using `char(233)`, `char(236)`, `char(243)` and `char(241)` with the same results.

Comment: You need to use a case sensitive collation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx:

> REPLACE performs comparisons based on the collation of the input. To
>   perform a comparison in a specified collation, you can use COLLATE to
>   apply an explicit collation to the input.

Guessing you want to apply something like `Latin1_General_CS_AS`:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(NetworkMemberId COLLATE 
Latin1_General_CS_AS,'é','e'),'í' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,'i'), 
'ó' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,'o'),'ñ' COLLATE 
Latin1_General_CS_AS,'n')
```

** EDIT **

Oops - missed accent sensitivity.